# Get-aduser by array employeenumber

Tags: powershell, active-directory, powershell-5.0

I'm trying to get the SamAccountName or Name attribute of AD users given by a fixed list of EmployeeNumbers attribute, for which I made an Array, then I want to print all of the SamAccountName attributes on screen to copy them to a web program.

```
$EmpID=(57885,57718,57806,57607,59281,57790,60097,61103,60552,57862,60698,61321,57730,57402,58546,57871,57886,57669,55878,52052,57811,60106,60741,61050,59279,61053,60735,50718,51459,57805,52343,57716,60618,57908,58356,60619,50937,61204,61099,60517,61015,61123,56078,54103,57947,57861,57991,60547,57915,58559,57010,59285,61003,61016,51620,56383,60621)

foreach($usr in $EmpID){get-aduser -filter "EmployeeNumber -eq '$($usr).EmployeeNumber'" -properties Name}
```

So I get one of this error for each value in the $EmpID array.

```
Get-ADUser : No se encuentra ningún parámetro de posición que acepte el argumento 'EmployeeNumber = '60621''.
En línea: 3 Carácter: 2
+ {get-aduser where "EmployeeNumber = '$usr'" -Properties Name}
+  ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidArgument: (:) [Get-ADUser], ParameterBindingException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : PositionalParameterNotFound,Microsoft.ActiveDirectory.Management.Commands.GetADUser
```

Comment: $usr is just the number. So change the filter to employeenumber -eq $usr

Comment: You need to check which property you try to compare. An ADUser has both `EmployeeNumber` and `EmployeeID`. Both properties are strings. My guessis that you are mixing the two properties because you hav variable `$EmpID`, but try to find the user via property `EmployeeNumber`. Also, prperty `Name` is returned by default whereas you will have to explicitely request for `EmployeeNumber` and/or `EmployeeID`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your variable $EmpID only contains a number, there is no "EmployeeNumber" property plus your closing parenthesis is in the wrong spot. You can see the difference by just running this

```
$EmpID=(57885,57718,57806,57607)
foreach($usr in $EmpID){$usr.employeenumber} # No output
```

and then this

```
$EmpID=(57885,57718,57806,57607)
foreach($usr in $EmpID){$usr}
```

So if you simply change your code to

```
$EmpID=(57885,57718,57806,57607,59281,57790,60097,61103,60552,57862,60698,61321,57730,57402,58546,57871,57886,57669,55878,52052,57811,60106,60741,61050,59279,61053,60735,50718,51459,57805,52343,57716,60618,57908,58356,60619,50937,61204,61099,60517,61015,61123,56078,54103,57947,57861,57991,60547,57915,58559,57010,59285,61003,61016,51620,56383,60621)

foreach($usr in $EmpID){get-aduser -filter "EmployeeNumber -eq '$usr'" -properties Name}
```

It should work fine. The way you're calling it now would require $EmpID to have objects with an EmployeeNumber property. Let's say you had a CSV with a single column and the header is EmployeeNumber. The following would be valid.

```
$EmpID = Import-CSV $somecsvfile

foreach($usr in $EmpID){get-aduser -filter "EmployeeNumber -eq '$($usr.EmployeeNumber)'" -properties Name}
```

Note the subexpression surrounds both the variable and the property name.

Comment: Great, it worked, strange thing happened while running it on PowerShell ISE, with powershell 5.1.17134.112
Runned the script 2 times and didn't got any result, nothing, not even errors.
3th time it worked just fine, getting all results.

Comment: Why do you say _"there is no "EmployeeNumber" property"_? An ADUser has **both** [EmployeeID and EmployeeNumber attributes](https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/12037.active-directory-get-aduser-default-and-extended-properties.aspx)

Comment: He is refering to my variable $EmpID, it's just a number, has no employeenumber property.

Answer (score -1):

As commented, an AD user has properties `EmployeeID` and `EmployeeNumber` (both defined as **string**).
Your question and code reveal you are mixing those two properties, so you need to check thoroughly first which of the two properties you need to use.

Then some remarks about your code:

- the `$EmpID` array definition does not need brackets and can be split up to multiple lines for clarity
- the code shows you use `Get-ADUser -Filter ..`, but the error message you show doesn't. There it reveals the usage of `Where-Object` with a wrong clause in which you are trying to **assign** something to another thing via the `=` operator.
- the code does not check if it actually could find a user with that EmployeeNumber or EmployeeID. If this would work at all, it would not output what you intend to receive, which seems to be the SamAccountName only,

Below code assumes you are using the `EmployeeID` property, but you need to check if this should not be `EmployeeNumber`

```
$EmpID= 57885,57718,57806,57607,59281,57790,60097,61103,60552,57862,60698,61321,57730,57402,
        58546,57871,57886,57669,55878,52052,57811,60106,60741,61050,59279,61053,60735,50718,
        51459,57805,52343,57716,60618,57908,58356,60619,50937,61204,61099,60517,61015,61123,
        56078,54103,57947,57861,57991,60547,57915,58559,57010,59285,61003,61016,51620,56383,60621

$result = foreach($id in $EmpID) {
    $user = Get-ADUser -Filter "EmployeeID -eq '$id'" -Properties EmployeeID, EmployeeNumber -ErrorAction SilentlyContinue
    if ($user) {
        # output the user property you want to store in the $result array
        $user.SamAccountName  # your question wants SamAccountName only..
    }
    else {
        Write-Warning "User with EmployeeID '$id' does not exist"
    }
}

# now you have an array with user SamAccountNames

# output on screen
$result
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, in this case i know all ID are positive results that's why i didn't considered that they could not be there.